# My -tpl file won't update!

Tags: php, smarty

I am running the site at www.euroworker.no, it's a linux server and the site has a backend editor. It's a smarty/php site, and when I try to update a few of the .tpl's (two or three) they don't update. I have tried uploading through FTP and that doesn't work either.

It runs on the [livecart](http://livecart.com/) system.

any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, Smarty is fetching the template from the cache and not rebuilding it. If it's a one-time thing, just empty the cache directory or directories (`templates_c`). If it happens more often, you may have to adjust smarty's caching behaviour in the configuration (among others, `$smarty->caching`and `$smarty->cache_lifetime`)

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that when you attempt to upload a new version it isn't updating the file? Or it's updating the file but the browser output does not conform to the new standards?

If it's the latter problem, delete all the files in your `template_c` directory. If it's the former problem, er, might want to check out ServerFault or SuperUser.

Comment: Sorry, I'm saying that the tpl doesn't pdat,e no browser output and when I load it back into the edtor it's the same as before I made any changes. I'll try to delete the cache. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure caching is the problem.. It was indeed the former problem, already posted this very question on Serverfault, no answers and this is kinda urgetn, shall check out superuser.

Thanks.